# Dropbox HTTP API, read file contents? Being given size + type before my string?

Tags: php, dropbox-api

```
$dropbox->getFile($path, $outFile);
```

which gives:

```
array(4) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(25) "New%20Text%20Document.txt"
  ["mime"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["meta"]=>
  object(stdClass)#7 (12) {
    ["revision"]=>
    int(13)
    ["rev"]=>
    string(9) "d1e5a1ef5"
    ["thumb_exists"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["bytes"]=>
    int(14)
    ["modified"]=>
    string(31) "Mon, 27 Jan 2014 01:54:42 +0000"
    ["client_mtime"]=>
    string(31) "Mon, 27 Jan 2014 01:54:41 +0000"
    ["path"]=>
    string(22) "/New Text Document.txt"
    ["is_dir"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["icon"]=>
    string(15) "page_white_text"
    ["root"]=>
    string(10) "app_folder"
    ["mime_type"]=>
    string(10) "text/plain"
    ["size"]=>
    string(8) "14 bytes"
  }
  ["data"]=>
  string(14) "bbvvcbcvbcvbcv"
}
```

im using :

```
<?php var_dump($file['data']); ?>
```

to get the data, however as you can see, its returned as:

```
string(14) "bbvvcbcvbcvbcv"
```

Normally i'd think to simply remove occurrences of ' " ' but what happens if the file contents contains those characters? I also need a way of removing the type and length info that has been added, cant seem to find any notes about this in the docs.

Thanks.

Comment: The '"' are just added by var_dump. Your real data is the content between them. You might drop stuff with unset($array[key]);

Answer (score 0):

**Facepalm**

```
var_dump();
```

will export with the all the mime types etc, that i was getting, simply change it to 'echo' or 'print_r' or similar and it becomes:

```
bbvvcbcvbcvbcv
```